# Wpf localization at runtime does not effect date format

Tags: wpf, date, localization, format

I am using localization with MarkupExtension like in [Christians Mosers Wpf tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html).
Changing the current language at runtime works well, but I found, that the date format is never updated. It always is formatted for en-US, no matter which language is selected.

I'm setting the current language like this

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = value;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = value;
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but using `LocBinding` from [Advanced WPF Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249369/Advanced-WPF-Localization) and a simple `DateTimeConverter` solved my problem. So The converter **DOES** get triggered when I switch the current language at runtime.

My XAML looks like:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource EntryBoxHeader}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <LocBinding StringFormat="{}{0:d}">
           <Binding Source="{x:Static System:DateTime.Now}" Path="." Converter="{StaticResource dtConvertor}"/>
        </LocBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to write a converter, to get my dates localized correctly in XAML (your `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` probably already contain the correct values!)!:

```
public sealed class DateTimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (value is DateTime)
                // HERE YOU HAVE TO PASS YOUR CULTURE INFO:
                return ((DateTime)value).ToString("d", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

...and then use it in your XAML (remember to declare it in the resource dictionary), as follows (the `converter:` prefix is related to the namespace where the `DateTimeToStringConverter` class is declared!):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:DateTimeToStringConverter x:Key="DateTimeToStringConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToStringConverter}}"  />
```

Comment: The converter does not get triggered when I switch the current language at runtime. Only if I navigate to another side and return (the content is reloaded), the date is displayed correcly.

Comment: @tabina That's true: usually you have to re-associate the DataContext or just manually update the bindings!

Comment: So if I want to make sure all bindings are uptodate, I have to call PropertyChanged on any property in any viewmodel? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: have you tried to re-associate the entire DataContext? It would have the same effect as updating every single binding! Try: this.DataContext = windowViewModel; (where this is your Windows object, and windowViewModel is the object containing your datetime properties)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
public static class LanguageManipulator
{
    public static void SetXmlFromCurrentCulture()
    {
        var curr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        var lang = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(curr.Name);

        SetCulture(lang, curr);

        var meteadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(lang);
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (FrameworkElement), meteadata);
    }

    private static void SetCulture(XmlLanguage lang, CultureInfo cult)
    {
        var propertynames = new[]
                                {
                                    "_equivalentCulture",
                                    "_specificCulture",
                                    "_compatibleCulture"
                                };

        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.ExactBinding | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        foreach (var name in propertynames)
        {
            var field = typeof (XmlLanguage).GetField(name, flags);
            if (field != null) field.SetValue(lang, cult);
        }

    }
}
```

And call SetXmlFromCurrentCulture after you have set the threads culture.

Comment: If I try to call OverrideMetadata more than once, I get an error that "PropertyMetadata" is already registered for the type "FrameworkElement".